# Why "Wrters Newsletter" in Writers newsletter?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Wrters but not Writers, does have some special meanings or just a typo?

[image: proof of Wrters]

[the original image link](http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/newsletters/writers-header.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a typo. I hadn't noticed that before!

Comment: it seems not be fixed in latest newsletter.

Comment: Yeah, and I don't know who to contact to get it corrected. If anyone else has any suggestions then please share!

Comment: @StevenDrennon - I'm used to the SE team noting what happens on the individual Metas, but since no one has responded I will go to them more directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fix has been deployed. Thanks for pointing this out.